# When do steady state solutions exist?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations

I just want some references as to when can we say based on the governing equation of a system, that a steady state solution to it exists? My specific question would be regarding the Navier-Stokes equation. When can we say that for a system, there exists steady-state solutions to the NSE? Any papers on the matter is also appreciated.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far?

Comment: I don't have the required mathematical knowledge, but I think that the existence of a steady state might depend on the existence of a minimum of the potential energy of the system, given the boundary conditions. However, I don't know if this is a correct/useful insight in the case of the NSE.

Comment: Steady state means that nothing is changing with time at each spatial location within the system.  Is that your understanding of the term?

Comment: More specifically the velocity field has spatial dependence and not time dependence. That's the one I'm working with.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't tell by intuition whether a flow is going to be steady state or transient?  If so, please provide two or three specific examples for which you are unable to make this determination.

Comment: If boundary conditions, external forces acting on fluid, and fluid's physical properties are steady in time, consistency requires that a steady state solution (i.e. velocity field) exist. Beginning from some initial conditions however the flow may take long to reach that steady state.